# Saving multiple versions of an img, with cv2.imwrite, f'string, inside of a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

**Problem:** My for loop places **all** elements of an array of unique strings **onto a single** image template instead of printing each unique array string object **onto a separate** but identical image template. The result is one image with unreadable text where 100 numbers where placed on top of each other.

**To place each unique value, I am using:**
f'string inside of a cv2.putText() function that is inside of a for loop.

**Question:** how do I rewrite this for loop or maybe the save/imwrite function to save 100 separate images to a folder, each pic with a unique name???

The full program (without f'string, that results in single image with 100 numbers written on top of each other) is attached below.

```
#Automated sports betting NFT images
#then generate an array of all possible outcomes of a soccer/football match using list(range(n))
#use f'string and cv2.puttext to add unique score to each image

import cv2
import numpy as np

#game_name str(team names)
e= "Man United v. Manchester"

    # should be a opensea or ETH ID number
g= "contract address/token ID"

pic_file = "cat_rainbow.png"
pic = cv2.imread(pic_file)

# resize to fit NFT platform requirements
img2 = cv2.resize(pic, (1100, 800))
h = img2


#uncoded template
#D as background image, (a,c,d) as un-unique variables on every image in this group

def Make_templ(a,b,c,d):
    cv2.putText(d, 'if the score of', (55, 255), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 3, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.putText(d, f'{a}', (100, 355), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 3, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.putText(d, f'is', (160, 455), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 3, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.putText(d, f'{b}', (360, 500), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 3, (0,0,255),3)
    cv2.putText(d, f'get...nft#{c}', (100, 600), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 3, (0, 0, 255), 3)

#create array for each individual teams possible scores
team1= np.array(list(range(10)))
team2=np.array(list(range(10)))

#arrays for all possible game outcomes in range ten between team 1 and 2
scores=[[x,y] for x in team1 for y in team2]
test_scores = scores
# print(test_scores)

outcomes = [str(e) for e in test_scores]


#loop to add each unique str(score) onto a separate image template
def Combine_score_templt():
    for i in outcomes:
        Make_templ(e,i,g,h)
        fpath = r"C:\Users\holli\PycharmProjects\NFT\multiple_nfts/cat.png"
        cv2.imwrite(fpath, img2)


#run program
Combine_score_templt()
```

I feel that the problem is my **saving function, cv2.imwrite** . I knew of a possible easy fix, **f'string**, and this fix was suggested all over the place in stackoverflow, but it did not help in my case unfortunately.

When I run this portion of code alone using f'string to create a unique file path, I get no output and the following error message.

```
def Combine_score_templt():
    for i in outcomes:
        Make_templ(e,i,g,h)
        fpath = f"C:\Users\holli\PycharmProjects\NFT\multiple_nfts/{i}.png"
        cv2.imwrite(fpath, img2)

Combine_score_templt()



  File "C:\Users\holli\PycharmProjects\NFT\game name obj.py", line 53
    fpath = f"C:\Users\holli\PycharmProjects\NFT\multiple_nfts/{i}.png"
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Your new `fpath` is no longer a raw string, and you have unescaped backslashes there. In `C:\Users.....` position 2 is the backslash, position 3 is the U... - `\U` is an escape sequence that should be followed by 8 hexadecimal digits. `s` is not a hexadecimal digit, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Dan Masek above left a comment that lead me down a path do answering my question on my own. He was the first person to explain to me where "unicode error" comes from. My file paths start with C:\Users. So path I wrote that wasn't in raw form was going to get this error.

I put a new file right into my local C file and cv2.write each image to there. Worked perfectly